# LBFGS or other optimization algorithms - implementations MATLAB

Tags: optimization

> Do you know some good free Matlab LBFGS implementations?

The only one I know (and use for the moment) is Liam Stewart's (it can be found at the following link: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~liam/software.shtml)

My interest is using these algorithms in shape optimization problems, where the sizes of the problems tend to get very large.

> Do you have any other suggestions of good and fast packages that can be used for optimizatioin problems?

Comment: Hi BeniBogosel, and welcome to Scicomp!  You may want to look the answers to this question as well: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/how-can-i-automate-the-process-of-optimizing-the-design-of-a-physical-object/2394#2394

Comment: matlab code LBFGS and wolfe condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'minFunc' MATLAB package (by Mark Schmidt) is one of the best available:
http://www.di.ens.fr/~mschmidt/Software/minFunc.html

This package is fairly mature and has been widely used in the ML community. It contains a stable L-BFGS implementation as well as related Newton and quasi-Newton optimization methods.

Answer (score 3):

A good Matlab implementation of limited-memory BFGS is the one accompanying Tim Kelley's book [*Iterative Methods for Optimization*](http://www.siam.org/books/kelley/fr18/index.php) (SIAM, 1999; PDF freely downloadable from the publisher's website). You can find his Matlab codes [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ctk/matlab_darts.html).

Regarding your second question: I would suggest implementing the algorithm yourself, since it is then much easier to adapt to the special structure of your specific problem (parameter tuning, exploiting derivative information, etc.).